# Android: specify circular reveal animation starting position?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, circularreveal

I currently have a circular reveal animation that starts from the very right of the toolbar. I want the initial circle center to start from the "search" icon which had me struggle to find an answer. I tried altering the `cx` and `xy` values and am unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated.

```
final Toolbar search_bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.search_toolbar);

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    int cx = search_bar.getWidth();
                    int cy = search_bar.getHeight()/2;

                    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);

                    Animator anim =
                            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(search_bar, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

                    search_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    anim.start();
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
public void startCircularReveal() {
    final View view = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    final View startView = findViewById(R.id.button_container);
    int cx = (startView.getLeft() + startView.getRight()) / 2;
    int cy = (startView.getTop() + startView.getBottom()) / 2;
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#6FA6FF"));
    int finalRadius = Math.max(cy , view.getHeight() - cy);
    Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
    anim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(200);
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    anim.start();
}
```

Change the view to the view that you want to do reveal on top of it ( usually root view ), and startView to your  "search" icon view, and onAnimationEnd do whatever you want after the reveal is finished.

**UPDATE**

If the reveal is not on top of your views, there is a little trick to fix it by adding this view to the bottom of your layout

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/custom_theme_color"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="invisible">
            </LinearLayout>
```

make sure that the view "view" set to the id of that layout

```
final View view = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

Basically what I did is adding a LinearLayout and set its width and height to match match_parent, so this view is on top of everything and this view is where the reveal will be on top of, and to make sure that view doesn't effect your layout I set visibility to invisible, and set it to visible right at the beginning of the reveal:

view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much this is quite informative. However, the animation now starts directly opposite side of the search icon which is rather strange.

Comment: What do you mean by "opposite side", can you explain more ?

Comment: As in the clipping circle now starts near the area of "Title" in the picture instead of on top of the "icon". I find this quite strange, your answer is logical.

Comment: I know why this happening, I will update the answer in a moment.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
revealView(listview, RssFragment.this.ll);

public  void revealView(View toBeRevealed, View frame)
{
    if (!ViewCompat.isAttachedToWindow(toBeRevealed))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
    {
        Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(toBeRevealed, (frame.getLeft() + frame.getRight()) / 2, (frame.getTop() + frame.getBottom()) / 2, 0.0f, (float) Math.max(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));
        toBeRevealed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        anim.start();
        return;
    }
    toBeRevealed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
enter i
nt cx = search_bar.getRight() * 5 / 6;
int cy = (search_bar.getTop() + search_bar.getBottom()) / 2;
```